# What does `pos` mean in the Linux kernel's list.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel, naming

The [Linux kernel's list.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) provides a number of macros for iterating over a its own linked list implementation. For example:

```
/**
 * list_for_each    -   iterate over a list
 * @pos:    the &struct list_head to use as a loop cursor.
 * @head:   the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); pos = pos->next)
```

What is the name of the `pos` parameter attempting to abbreviate? (What does `pos` stand for / mean?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is abbreviating "position", it is showing the current cursor position.

Comment: so should have a locking mechanism for answers :P

Answer (score 3):

It means "position", as in the current position in the list.